# Grep multiple strings match results to string

Tags: linux, grep

Been searching for this with no success.  Running a search through our logs and need to search multiple patterns and match that to a source IP in our logs.  Looking to just get a clean output or the term I searched and the result.

What I run:

```
grep "term1\|term2\|term3\|term4\|term5" file.log | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | sort
```

It gives me a nice list of IP addresses.  The problem is I'm not sure which matches up with the terms I am searching.  Is there an obvious way I'm missing that can show that?

Comment: One (lame) workaround is to grep each term by itself, i.e.
`for term in echo "term1 term2"; do echo "$term" ; grep $term file.log | grep "..."; done`

Comment: Are the terms always in the same field in the log? Use `awk` and print that field.

Comment: @npit I thought about just doing each on its own, but that would mean far more time and this could have better future use I think.  Barmar the data is always in the same fields.  Thought I'm not that good with Awk currently.

Comment: @Barmar ^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably easier done with `awk`. Assuming the IP is in field 1, and the term is in field 5:

```
awk '$5 ~ /term1|term2|term3|term4|term5/ { print $1, $5 }' file.log
```

This will print the IP and the field containing the matching term.

Comment: Well I thought this was a solid answer even though someone down voted it.  Thanks for the help!  I managed to solve the issue thanks!